# Build does not start on development PC

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, windows-7, .net-4.5

I wrote a program that reads customers from an ascii file and writes them into a mysql DB.

When I use the VS2013 debugger (with F5) in release mode everything works perfect. But when I start the exe-file from the release directory, no windows are visible. In the windows log file, I see nothing and in the task manager I see my app 3 times and cannot close them. The only thing that I can do is to restart my PC.

I have tried to create a Setup program with InstallShield, but I have the same problem with the setup.exe file as with my program, It does not start.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Check your application event log for errors.

Comment: when it runs for first time and you close it, does it still appear in task manager ? is it properly disposed ?

Comment: Try adding a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` to the beginning of the application. Then you can attach and step through it.

Comment: Thx but:
1. In the application event log is no error/warning visuable
2. I cannot close the program because I cannot see the window
I tried to make an empty program with .net 4.5 and still the problem stays.